# PHP Contact form - Need to use SMTP

Tags: php, html, smtp

So i'm fairly new to php and have been using public templates and stuff to create a very simple contact form here:
https://lewis-morley.co.uk/contact/

Everything works but the issue is that the host I use blocks PHPMail so no emails are actually coming through and I need to recode it to work in SMTP, I do not have access to the php.ini file.

Any pointers?

For reference here is the contact form code:
https://lewis-morley.co.uk/sources.html

Thanks :)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: To make a long story short, 1. Use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which doesn't rely on `mail()` or Sendmail 2. Get an external SMTP service like, say, Amazon SES, to deliver the mail for you